# Django bulk creation: too many terms in compound SELECT

Tags: python, django

So I am trying to generate a lot of data to test my database and I am using the following statement to generate ItemLists:

```
for __ in range(0, 1000):
    list_cache = []
    for __ in range(0, 10000):
        list_cache.append(ItemList())
    ItemList.objects.bulk_create(list_cache, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

When I try to execute the code the error `django.db.utils.OperationalError: too many terms in compound SELECT` shows up. It originates from the last line of the code sample.

> I found that when I move the `list_cache` outside of both for loops and only call the `bulk_create` once, it works fine (code below). But as I don't want a one million entries in one statement, I split it as you can see above.
>
> ```
> list_cache = []
> for __ in range(0, 1000):
>     for __ in range(0, 10000):
>         list_cache.append(ItemList())
> ItemList.objects.bulk_create(list_cache, ignore_conflicts=True)
> ```

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: if you are using sqlite, the [max limit for compound select is 500](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_compound_select).

Comment: I am using SQLlite, but I am not selecting, am I? @NalinDobhal

Comment: @NalinDobhal Plus it works when adding all million entries the second way!